# Thread in Python : class attribute (list) not thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, list, class, object

I am trying to understand Threads in Python.

**The code**

And now I have a problem, which I have surrounded in one simple class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import threading

class myClassWithThread(threading.Thread):

    __propertyThatShouldNotBeShared = []
    __id = None
    def __init__(self, id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__id = id

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.dummy1()
            self.dummy2()

    def dummy1(self):
        if self.__id == 2:
            self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared.append("Test value")


    def dummy2(self):
        for data in self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared:
            print self.__id
            print data
            self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared.remove(data)



obj1 = myClassWithThread(1)
obj2 = myClassWithThread(2)
obj3 = myClassWithThread(3)

obj1.start()
obj2.start()
obj3.start()
```

**Description**

Here is what the class does :
The class has two attributes :

- `__id` which is an identifier for the object, given when the constructor is called
- `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` is a list and will contain a text value

Now the methods

- `run()` contains an infinite loop in which I call `dummy1()` and then `dummy2()`
- `dummy1()` which adds to attribute (list) `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` the value "Test value" only IF the `__id` of the object is equal to 2
- `dummy2()` checks if the size of the list `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` is strictly superior to 0, then

  - for each value in `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` it prints the id of
  - the object and the value contained in `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared`
  - then it removes the value

Here is the output that I get when I launch the program :

```
21

Test valueTest value

2
Test value
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PROG\myFace\python\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\PROG\myFace\myProject\ghos2\src\Tests\threadDeMerde.py", line 15, in run
    self.dummy2()
  File "E:\PROG\myFace\myProject\ghos2\src\Tests\threadDeMerde.py", line 27, in dummy2
    self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared.remove(data)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

**The problem**

As you can see in the first line of the output I get this "1"...which means that, at some point, the object with the id "1" tries to print something on the screen...and actually it does! 
But this should be impossible!
Only object with id "2" should be able to print anything!

What is the problem in this code ? Or what is the problem with my logic?

Comment: `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` is a class member and not an instance member.

Comment: Hmm interesting ! How do I make it an instance member ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
class myClassWithThread(threading.Thread):
    __propertyThatShouldNotBeShared = []
```

It defines one list for all objects which is shared. You should do this:

```
class myClassWithThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared = []
        # the other code goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

There are *two* problems here—the one you asked about, thread-safety, and the one you didn't, the difference between class and instance attributes.

---

It's the latter that's causing your actual problem. A class attribute is shared by all instances of the class. It has nothing to do with whether those instances are accessed on a single thread or on multiple threads; there's only one `__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared` that's shared by everyone. If you want an instance attribute, you have to define it on the instance, not on the class. Like this:

```
class myClassWithThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared = []
```

---

Once you do that, each instance has its own copy of __propertyThatShouldNotBeShared, and each lives on its own thread, so there is no thread-safety issue possible.

However, your original code *does* have a thread-safety problem.

Almost nothing is automatically thread-safe (aka "synchronized"); exceptions (like [`queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)) will say so explicitly, and be meant specifically for threaded programming.

You can avoid this in three ways:

- Don't share anything.
- Don't mutate anything you share.
- Don't mutate anything you share unless it's protected by an appropriate synchronization object.

The last one is of course the most flexible, but also the most complicated. In fact, it's at the center of why people consider threaded programming hard.

The short version is, everywhere you modify *or access* shared mutable data like `self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared`, you need to be holding some kind of synchronization object, like a [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects). For example:

```
class myClassWithThread(threading.Thread):
    __lock = threading.Lock()
    # etc.

    def dummy1(self):
        if self.__id == 2:
            with self.__lock:
                self.__propertyThatShouldNotBeShared.append("Test value")
```

If you stick to CPython, and to built-in types, you can often get away with ignoring locks. But "often" in threaded programming is just a synonym for "always during testing and debugging, right up until the release or big presentation, when it suddenly begins failing". Unless you want to learn the rules for how the Global Interpreter Lock and the built-in types work in CPython, don't rely on this.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer :) So far I am not sharing anything...That's why I was so surprised of getting "shared"-data-behavior or in other words synchronization problem :)

Comment: @user3147478: I don't think you were actually seeing a synchronization problem. But on top of the problem you _were_ seeing, it's quite possible that every so often (rarely—but that just makes it more painful to debug) one thread would see the shared list half-way through being updated by the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables in Python are just that: shared by all instances of the class. You need an instance variable, which you usually define inside `__init__`. Remove the class-level declarations (and the double leading underscores, they're for name mangling which you don't need here.)

Comment: Yep, my problem was with Python itself that I did not learn correctly (totally my bad). Now I am realizing that I have programmed everything in my project with class attributes ! I am just surprised that my project has been working till today with crashing :) Thank you for your reply !